# ChartJS - x axis labels orientation

Tags: rotation, label, chart.js, orientation, axis

Is it possible to change x-axis label orientation like marked area on the screenshot? I was trying rotate labels with `afterCalculateTickRotation` but they weren't flipped. Mirror option doesn't work also.

[image: rtjs]

[Example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-6cd7v)

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle etc. and I will look into it

Comment: Hi, I added link to example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what you are asking for but it's not beautiful because chart.js lacks support to do it properly. So I solved it with some hard coded padding. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-4ygr1

It's the minRotation and maxRotation you should work with. The labels anchoring point should shift when the rotation goes below zero but they don't. Instead they rotate into the chart but this can be avoided with padding.

A side effect of the padding is that the legend placement broke so i put it in the top instead.

Another unwanted behavior is that the text is aligned to the right. There is an open issue about that: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4193

Comment: Thanks! This is the effect I want to achieve but the sad thing is it doesn't happen "out of the box". For this example data it's OK but longer labels will overlap chart area, so I have to hardcode padding etc.